# Chord detection algorithm in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, web-audio-api

I found an algorithm for detecting chords using a microphone online but it doesn't work. The error lies in trying to get the user feedback. Here is the code:

```
var ChordDetect = function(options) {

var _cd = {};

var _audio;
var _analyser;
var _microphone;
var _volume;
var _canvas;
var _canvasContext;

var _startAnimation;
var _animateSpectrum;
var _animateSpectrogram

var _defaults = {
    volume: 0.0,
    fftSize: 1024,
    smoothing: 0,
    mode: 'spectrum',
    canvasId: 'canvas'
};

var _attrs = _.defaults(options, _defaults);

var _error = function(message) {
    console.log("Error: " + message);
};

_cd.listen = function() {

    if (typeof AudioContext !== 'undefined') {
        _audio = new AudioContext();
    } else if (typeof webkitAudioContext !== 'undefined') {
        _audio = new webkitAudioContext();
    } else {
        _error('Audio context not supported!'); 
    }

    if (_audio) {

        _analyser = _audio.createAnalyser();
        _analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = _attrs.smoothing;
        _analyser.fftSize = _attrs.fftSize;

        var gainNode = _audio.createGain();
        _volume = gainNode.gain;
        _cd.setVolume(_attrs.volume);

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia( { audio: true }, function(stream) {

            _microphone = _audio.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
            _microphone.connect(_analyser);

            _analyser.connect(gainNode);
            gainNode.connect(_audio.destination);

            _startAnimation(_attrs.mode);

         },  _error('failed to get user media.') );

    }

};

var _startAnimation = function(mode) {

    _canvas = document.getElementById(_attrs.canvasId);

    if (_canvas.getContext) { 

        _canvasContext = _canvas.getContext('2d');
        _requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
            function(callback) {
                return setTimeout(callback, 1);
            };


        switch (mode) {

            case 'spectrum':
                _animateSpectrum();
            break;

            case 'spectrogram':
            default:
                _animateSpectrogram();
            break;
        }

    } else {

        _error('Failed to find canvas with id: ' + _attrs.canvasId);

    }

};

_animateSpectrum = function() {

        var draw = function() {

            _canvasContext.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .01)';
            _canvasContext.beginPath();
            _canvasContext.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            _canvasContext.fill();
            _canvasContext.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ', ' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ', ' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ')';

            var blockWidth = canvas.width / (_attrs.fftSize / 2);
            var blockHeight = canvas.height / 256;

            var frequencyArray = new Uint8Array(_analyser.frequencyBinCount);
            _analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyArray);

            for (var i = 0; i < frequencyArray.length; i++) {
                _canvasContext.beginPath();
                _canvasContext.rect(i * blockWidth, canvas.height, blockWidth, -1 * frequencyArray[i] * blockHeight); 
                _canvasContext.fill();
            }

            _requestAnimationFrame(draw);

        };

        draw();

};

_animateSpectrogram = function() {

    var tempCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var tempContext = tempCanvas.getContext('2d');

    var colorScale = chroma.scales.hot().domain([0, 255]); 

    var blockWidth = canvas.width / (_attrs.fftSize / 2);
    var blockHeight = canvas.height / 256;

    tempCanvas.width = _canvas.width;
    tempCanvas.height =  _canvas.height;

    var draw = function() {

        var frequencyArray = new Uint8Array(_analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        _analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyArray);

        // copy current canvas to tempCanvas
        tempContext.drawImage(_canvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        for (var i = 0; i < frequencyArray.length; i++) {
            _canvasContext.fillStyle = colorScale(frequencyArray[i]).hex(); 
            _canvasContext.fillRect(canvas.width - blockWidth, canvas.height - i * blockHeight, blockWidth, blockHeight);
        }

        _canvasContext.translate(-1 * blockWidth, 0);
        _canvasContext.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0, tempCanvas.width, tempCanvas.height, 0, 0, _canvas.width, _canvas.height);
        _canvasContext.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

        _requestAnimationFrame(draw);

    };

    draw();

}

// set volume 0.0 - 1.0
_cd.setVolume = function(vol) {

    if (vol > 1.0) vol = 1.0;
    if (vol < 0.0) vol = 0.0;
    _volume.value = vol;
    console.log("changed volume: " + _volume.value);

};

_cd.volumeUp = function() {

    _cd.setVolume(_volume.value + 0.1);

};

_cd.volumeDown = function() {

    _cd.setVolume(_volume.value - 0.1);

};

_cd.getVolume = function() {
    return _volume.value;
};

return _cd;

};
```

The error is in the `cd.listen` function. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have is very old and your error may be because of depreciated calls.

Change the call to getUserMedia in the listen function to use promises. Please NOTE I removed all the underscores as they just look crazy. You will have to work them out yourself.

Bad code (without `_`) to be replaced...

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio : true
    }, function (stream) {
        microphone = audio.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        microphone.connect(analyser);
        analyser.connect(gainNode);
        gainNode.connect(audio.destination);
        startAnimation(attrs.mode);
    }, error('failed to get user media.')
);
```

...with the following

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio : true })
    .then( function (stream) {
        microphone = audio.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        microphone.connect(analyser);
        analyser.connect(gainNode);
        gainNode.connect(audio.destination);
        startAnimation(attrs.mode);
    })
    .catch(()=>error('failed to get user media.'));
```

See [getUserMedia at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) for more info